# Counting login attempts in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm a total newbie to web development, and here is what I've tried:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    attempt = 0
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login requested for OpenID="%s", remember_me=%s' %
              (form.openid.data, str(form.remember_me.data)))
        return redirect('/index')
    attempt += 1
    flash('Attempt(s)="%d"' % attempt)
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)
```

The output is always `Attempt(s)="1"`, while I expect the number to increase by 1 each time `form.validate_on_submit()` fails.

I observed that when I press `Sign In` button, `login` page is refreshed. However, all text I inputted in the text fields remained there, so I suppose `form = LoginForm()` wasn't executed.(If a brand new `LoginForm` is created, how can these text still be there?) Thus I put the statement `attempt = 0` above `form = LoginForm()`, hoping it not to be executed each time `Sign In` is pressed, but apparently this does't work.

I think the problem is that I don't know what happened when I pressed `Sign In`. Is the function `login` called again? If so, it's called by whom?

Here is the content of `login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Sign In</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="login">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <p>
          Please enter your OpenID:<br>
          {{ form.openid(size=80) }}<br>
      </p>
      <p>{{ form.remember_me }} Remember Me</p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The web is stateless. Every time you press a submit button, your browser calls the URL associated with that form; that URL is routed to your `login()` handler function, which runs from the start. The function itself has no memory of previous calls (and nor would you want it to, otherwise all users of your site would get the same login count). The form is populated from the data sent in the submit request, which is sent automatically to the form instantation by the flask-wtf library.

You need to store that count somewhere between calls. A good place to do that is in a cookie; Flask includes the [sessions API](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions) to make this simpler.

Comment: When I write `<p><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></p>` in `login.html`, that button is automatically routed to `'/login'`, which further calls `login()`. Am I right?

Comment: Well, it's not automatically routed anywhere; the submit button is presumably inside a form element - something like `<form action="/login">` - and it's the action that determines where it sends to. For the rest, though, you're correct.

Comment: But sir, the `action` attribute of the surrounding `<form>` is an empty string. See my updated question.

Comment: Well, then it submits to the current URL, ie the same place you originally went to in order to see the empty form.

Comment: Last question before I accept this answer: When `login()` is called again, a new `LoginForm` object is created, on which `validate_on_submit()` is applied. However, the data(i.e. the text I inputed before press `Sign In` button) to be validated is still retained, although it is likely that the last `LoginForm` object has already been collected by `gc`. How does Flask achieve this?

Comment: I mentioned that in the answer. The text is submitted with the form, and automatically passed into the new object instantation by flask-wtf.

Comment: A cookie is not a good idea as "No data from the browser is trustworth". You should rather use the session flask object. An idea is to increase the attempt counts by one every time they fail and reset it when they login or reset their password. After a number failed attempts, for example 3, you can set a time interval within you can directly reject the login requests. Finally, every time you set a time interval it can be greater than the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this and it worked

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def home():
    session['attempt'] = 5
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    session['username'] = username
    password = request.form.get('password')
    if username and password and username in users and users[username] == password:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    attempt= session.get('attempt')
    attempt -= 1
    session['attempt']=attempt
    #print(attempt,flush=True)
    if attempt==1:
        client_ip= session.get('client_ip')
        flash('This is your last attempt, %s will be blocked for 24hr, Attempt %d of 5'  % (client_ip,attempt), 'error')
    else:
        flash('Invalid login credentials, Attempts %d of 5'  % attempt, 'error')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```